# Сложность алгоритма

Tags: java, алгоритм, сложность, асимптотика

Какую сложность имеет алгоритм данной функции ? О(n)?
Если да, то можно объяснить почему?

```
public static void merge(ArrayList a, ArrayList b){
    if(a.size() == b.size()){
        for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.size(); i+=2, j++){
            a.add(i+1,b.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: потому что есть цикл на n/2 итераций, а само значение f(n) принято округлять до одного n в максимальной степени, содержащейся в f(n).

Comment: Попробуй почитать статью [«вычислительная сложность»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) в Википедии, должно быть все понятно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**O(n^2)**

Рассмотрим выражение

```
a.add(i+1,b.get(j));
```

Оно работает за O(N) - *чтобы вставить элемент в ArrayList, нужно часть его элементов передвинуть*

```
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.size(); i+=2, j++)
```

Сам по себе этот цикл даёт умножение асимптотики на N.

Итого получаем O(N*N)=O(N^2)

p.s. был бы LinkedList, то был бы O(N), т.к. добавление в LinkedList занимает О(1)

Answer (score 4):

Почитайте Сэджвика, например (книга хорошая, по сравнению с Кнутом ее хотя бы понять проще). Сложность - это, если просто, количество операций, выполняемых алгоритмом. Чтобы не считать каждую мелочь, то выбирают операцию, которая выполняется за константное время (не зависит от n), и считается элементарной. Если посмотреть реализацию операции вставки в ArrayList, то будет ясно, что она имеет сложность O(N), у нее элементарная операция - это сдвиг одного элемента вправо. Далее считается количество выполнения таких операций на языке О-символики. У вас эта команда выполнится `a.size()(это и есть n)/2 * n/2 (в среднем)` раз, но на языке О-символики это то же самое, что О(n^2)

Comment: Учитывая реализацию ArrayList, как-то очень странно учитывать .add() за единицу

Comment: @danpetruk да, согласен, спасибо, сейчас исправлю